# Error when using the html_table function from the rvest package

Tags: html, r, web-scraping, rvest

I am attempting to perform some web-scraping using `rvest` on a webpage behind a login and I have successfully connected to the web page and can access the HTML. (For those interested I am scraping fantasy rugby player statistics).

I am trying to pass the data into a data frame using this code:

```
loginsession %>% 
   read_html() %>% 
   html_elements('.general') %>%
   html_table(fill = T) %>% 
   data.frame()
```

But am met with this error:

```
Error in matrix(unlist(values), ncol = width, byrow = TRUE) : 'data' must be of a vector type, was 'NULL'
```

The html reads like this:

```
 [1] <div class="item hider general club" style="text-align: left"><strong>Club</strong></div>\n
 [2] <div class="item hider general nationality" style="text-align: left"><strong>Nat</strong></div>\n
 [3] <div class="item hider general salary"><strong>Salary</strong></div>\n
 [4] <div class="item hider general points"><strong>Points</strong></div>\n
 [5] <div class="item hider general selectionCount"><strong>Selected</strong></div>\n
 [6] <div class="item hider general internationalCaps"><strong>Caps</strong></div>\n
 [7] <div class="item hider general age"><strong>Age</strong></div>\n
 [8] <div class="item hider general recommendation scout-report"><strong>Recm</strong></div>\n
 [9] <div class="item hider general form-display" style="text-align: left"><strong>Form</strong></div>\n
[10] <div class="item hider general averageRating"><strong>Avg</strong></div>\n
[11] <div class="item hider general minutesPlayed"><strong>Mins</strong></div>\n
[12] <div class="item hider general pointsPerGame"><strong>Pts/80</strong></div>\n
[13] <div class="item hider general attackingPointsPerGame"><strong>Att/80</strong></div>\n
[14] <div class="item hider general defensivePointsPerGame"><strong>Def/80</strong></div>\n
[15] <div class="item hider general kickingPointsPerGame"><strong>K/80</strong></div>\n
[16] <div class="item hider general club" style="text-align: left">\n<div class="logo full"><a class="popup" data-url="/fant ...
[17] <div class="item hider general nationality" style="text-align: left">\n<i class="flag GB-ENG"></i><span class="hide-for ...
[18] <div class="item hider general salary">\n                                                                               ...
[19] <div class="item hider general points">\n                                                                               ...
[20] <div class="item hider general selectionCount">\n                                                            13%\n      ...
```

Comment: Try updating the package, refer https://github.com/tidyverse/rvest/issues/318

Answer (score 0):

`html_table` requires an HTML table definition (with tags TABLE, TH, TR, TD …). Your HTML is a series of divisions (DIV) presumably styled with CSS (class = "…") to *look like* an HTML table.

You can try extracting the desired elements as vectors, using *CSS-selectors*. Example:

```
## raw html %>%
html_node("div.item.hider.general > strong")
```

find tutorials on CSS selectors [here](https://duckduckgo.com/?q=css%20selectors)

Comment: This is very useful! Thank you. Could you provide an example of how I would access the value (13%) on line [20] above? 
I think this is the starting point, but I don't know how to get the value.
html %>% html_node("div.item.hider.general.selectionCount")

Comment: I found an interesting solution to this in the end. By using read_html() %>% 
    html_nodes(item) %>% html_text2(), where item is the name of a row within the HTML table